# How can I globally style the scrollbar in Vuetify according to the user's theme?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I've created a custom css file that applies styles to the global scrollbar! But, I'd like to only show a dark scrollbar to users when $vuetify.theme.dark is set to true.

Is there a way that I can apply scrollbar css globally once that theme variable changes?

Here's my App.vue file

```
<template>
  <v-app
    id="inspire"
    :style="{ background: $vuetify.theme.themes[theme].background }"
  >
    <header-bar />
    <v-main>
      <v-container fluid fill-height>
        <keep-alive>
          <router-view />
        </keep-alive>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import HeaderBar from "./components/Navigation/HeaderBar.vue";
import store from "./store";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HeaderBar,
  },
  computed: {
    theme() {
      return this.$vuetify.theme.dark ? "dark" : "light";
    },
  },
  store: store,
  beforeCreate() {
    this.$store.commit("initializeStore");

    this.$vuetify.theme.dark = this.$store.state.DarkMode;
  },
};
</script>

<style>
@import "./DarkScrollbar.css";

html {
  overflow: auto !important;
}

.v-btn.theme--light.v-btn--has-bg:not(.primary):not(.success):not(.error) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
</style>
```

In the above, I've created a computed variable "theme" to store the theme's name, which I believe I can place a watcher and trigger a function call on change.

Here's the contents of the DarkScrollbar.css file that I'm wanting to dynamically toggle!

```
/* Dark Scrollbar CSS */
::placeholder {
  color: #b2aba1;
}
input:-webkit-autofill,
textarea:-webkit-autofill,
select:-webkit-autofill {
  background-color: #555b00 !important;
  color: #e8e6e3 !important;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background-color: #202324;
  color: #aba499;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #454a4d;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: #575e62;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
  background-color: #484e51;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
  background-color: #181a1b;
}
::selection {
  background-color: #004daa !important;
  color: #e8e6e3 !important;
}
::-moz-selection {
  background-color: #004daa !important;
  color: #e8e6e3 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've actually just fixed this myself. I'll post the answer here so that other folks might be able to use this too! Programatically adding and removing a class on the ***body*** element allows you to toggle scrollbar styling.

In my computed property, I just had to add the class based on Vuetify's selected theme.

```
computed: {
  theme() {
    const bodyElement = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    if (this.$vuetify.theme.dark == true) {
      bodyElement.classList = "darkScrollbar";
    } else {
      bodyElement.classList = "";
    }
    return this.$vuetify.theme.dark ? "dark" : "light";
  },
},
```

In my custom CSS file that I import, I added body as well as the custom class to each ::webkit style rule.

```
body.darkScrollbar::placeholder {
  color: #b2aba1;
}
body.darkScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background-color: #202324;
  color: #aba499;
}
body.darkScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #454a4d;
}
body.darkScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: #575e62;
}
body.darkScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
  background-color: #484e51;
}
body.darkScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
  background-color: #181a1b;
}
body.darkScrollbar::selection {
  background-color: #004daa !important;
  color: #e8e6e3 !important;
}
body.darkScrollbar::-moz-selection {
  background-color: #004daa !important;
  color: #e8e6e3 !important;
}
body.darkScrollbar input:-webkit-autofill,
body.darkScrollbar textarea:-webkit-autofill,
body.darkScrollbar select:-webkit-autofill {
  background-color: #555b00 !important;
  color: #e8e6e3 !important;
}
```

Comment: I have searched hours for a better solution, without a computed prop, but it seems that this is really the easiest way. Thank you!